# Can I take a velocity figure for a Fix Version in eazyBI JIRA App and use it calculate the velocity of a subset Fix Version? e.g. beta 1, beta 2, etc

Tags: jira, mdx, jira-plugin, mondrian, mdx-query

In our JIRA, we have a Fix Version(FV) 1 that covers everything in Release 1. For this overarching Release 1 we have a velocity that is an average of the last 5 sprints.

We also have FVs 1a, 1b and 1c that are subsets of FV 1.

So far, I've created the dashboards for FV 1, 1a, 1b and 1c but the average velocity is calculated from issues in that specific FV and not from FV 1.

I want to use the velocity from FV 1 and apply it to FVs 1a, 1b and 1c.

I've managed to create a constant value that I can use across all FVs, but this has to be edited manually each sprint as the velocity changes.

Is there a way to create something automated that achieves the same thing so that all dashboards are using the same velocity?